# Retrieve RelativeLayout inside included layout get null

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, include, xml-layout

i get null pointer error in line :

```
rl.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.headerbackground);
```

MainActivity code:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View mainLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_layout, null, false);
View includedHeader = mainLayout.findViewById(R.id.header);
RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) includedHeader.findViewById(R.id.header_root);
rl.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.headerbackground);
setContentView(mainLayout);
```

in `main_layout.xml` I include `header_layout` :

```
<include android:id="@+id/header" layout="@layout/header_layout"/>
```

and in `header_layout.xml`:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/header_root" />
```

question: why rl is null and how access to it in my code?

EDITED: logcat logs(mainActivity.java:58 is rl.setBackground(R.drawable.headerbackround) in my code):

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.npi.blureffect.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:58)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
```

Comment: post ur log and full code pls..

Comment: what is line no 58 in `MainActivity.java`?

Comment: @SilentKiller: rl.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.headerbackground);

Comment: That indicates `rl` is null even after `RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) includedHeader.findViewById(R.id.header_root);`. Are you sure you have layout `header_root` in xml `header`. If yes, Clean build and check

Comment: @MagicalPhoenixϡ : yes im sure i check it again. if i retrive other element of header_layout.xml program run without error but only for access to Relative layout genereate error. why??

Answer (score 0):

You are setting your ContentView in the wrong order. You have to first set the ContentView, then change the background color :

```
setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);
// the include tag is included dynamically in the root view
RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.header_root);
rl.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.headerbackground);
```

Comment: first time i coded like this but return null pointer. rl is in lncluded layout and Unfortunately this not work

Answer (score 0):

Instead of fetching it from `includedHeader` try to fetch it directly from `mainLayout`. You don't need to assign id to include tag and bind it in java. You can directly fetch views

Replace

```
RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) includedHeader.findViewById(R.id.header_root);
```

with

```
RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) mainLayout.findViewById(R.id.header_root);
```

Your code will be

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View mainLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_layout, null, false);
RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) mainLayout.findViewById(R.id.header_root);
rl.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.headerbackground);
setContentView(mainLayout);
```

Comment: nullPoitnterExeption again:(

Comment: @mk72 post logcat output

Answer (score 0):

You should try debugging and see at line `rl.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.headerbackground);` if the variable rl is null.
In case it's not then maybe the drawable is null.

EDIT:

`rl` is null because `includedHeader` must be null.
Try removing the line `View includedHeader = mainLayout.findViewById(R.id.header);` and replace with `RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) mainLayout.findViewById(R.id.header_root);`
Afterwards check to see if mainLayout or rl are null (while debugging)

EDIT 2:

When you are creating reusable layouts (ones that will be later included using `include`) it's always best to make the root a `FrameLayout`

Also check this [page](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html) out and maybe you can use the `<merge>` tag instead.

Comment: i check it. rl is null

Comment: yes. i find out when i attempt to retrive other element(view) of header_layout.xml everything is ok but only when i want access to root view of header_layout.xml  app stopped with null pointer error

Comment: check to see if you have some ids appearing multiple times in the app. In other words try to change `header_root` to `header_root_new` for example.

Comment: no . i cheked it. if i add a viewGroup like relativeLayout to top of the hader_layout and make hader_root a child of it error will gone but why???? why root view of included layout is null?

Answer (score 0):

Some code like your works very well for me in Android 4.2.2 until nowadays.

But, I don't know why, after Android 4.4 a (RelativeLayout) included dynamically inside another (RelativeLayout) returns null after a rootLayout.findViewById( ... ).

In this cases, you can safely find by views using root layout directly!

So, to correct work this code you must include only one line of code:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) 
getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View mainLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_layout, null, false);
View includedHeader = mainLayout.findViewById(R.id.header);
RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) includedHeader.findViewById(R.id.header_root);

if ( rl == null ) { rl = includedHeader; } // include this line

rl.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.headerbackground);
setContentView(mainLayout);
```

This code works succesfully for all Androids before and after 4.4

Berst regards!